# How do I resolve this issue when attempting to install libv8 v3.11.8.9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, linode, therubyracer

The installation of the libv8 gem (anything after v3.3.10) fails with a message 'Killed'.

I'm including libv8 & therubyracer in my Gemfile:

```
group :production, :staging do
  gem 'libv8'
  gem 'therubyracer'
end
```

The `bundle update` works fine locally (Mac OS X ). When I do a `cap staging deploy`, the deploy fails with:

```
  * 2013-01-04 19:17:51 executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /path/to/app/app-staging/releases/20130105001748 && bundle install --gemfile /path/to/app/app-staging/releases/20130105001748/Gemfile --path /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development"
    servers: ["staging.app.com"]
    [staging.app.com] executing command
 ** [out :: staging.app.com] bash: line 1:  4324 Killed                  bundle install --gemfile /path/to/app/app-staging/releases/20130105001748/Gemfile --path /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development
    command finished in 48980ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /path/to/app/app-staging/releases/20130105001748; true"
    servers: ["staging.app.com"]
    [staging.app.com] executing command
    command finished in 1928ms
failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.3-p327@app' -c 'cd /path/to/app/app-staging/releases/20130105001748 && bundle install --gemfile /path/to/app/app-staging/releases/20130105001748/Gemfile --path /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development'" on staging.app.com
```

If I go to the server (Debian 6 32bit on Linode, Linux 3.5.2-linode45) and run `bundle exec gem install libv8 -v '3.11.8.9'`, it fails with:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing libv8:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile
Using compiler: /usr/bin/g++
g++: Internal error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[1]: *** [/path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/v8_base/src/api.o] Error 1
make: *** [ia32.release] Error 2
/path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/ext/libv8/location.rb:36:in `block in verify_installation!': libv8 did not install properly, expected binary v8 archive '/path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a'to exist, but it was not found (Libv8::Location::Vendor::ArchiveNotFound)
  from /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `each'
  from /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `verify_installation!'
  from /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/ext/libv8/location.rb:26:in `install!'
  from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'
GYP_GENERATORS=make \
  build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
                -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. \
                -Dv8_target_arch=ia32 \
                -S.ia32 -Dhost_arch=ia32
make[1]: Entering directory `/path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out'
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/allocation.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/cached-powers.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/conversions.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/diy-fp.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/fast-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/fixed-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/once.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/preparse-data.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/preparser.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/preparser-api.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/scanner.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/strtod.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/token.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/unicode.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/utils.o
  AR(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libpreparser_lib.a
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/preparser/preparser/preparser-process.o
  LINK(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/preparser
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/v8_base/src/accessors.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/v8_base/src/allocation.o
  CXX(target) /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/v8_base/src/api.o
make[1]: Leaving directory `/path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/vendor/v8/out'


Gem files will remain installed in /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /path/to/app/app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.9/ext/libv8/gem_make.out
```

At the moment, I have to specify old versions of therubyracer & libv8 in order to get my deploy to be successful:

```
group :production, :staging do
  gem 'libv8', '~> 3.3.10'
  gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.10.2'
end
```

It seems like [this Issue](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/215) might be related.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: It seems there is a problem with the disk space. You can try to swap with the help of https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things *were* sorted out on January 7th, 2013 ... but everything fell apart again one day later. Another day after *that*, and it looks like things are back together again!

therubyracer v0.11.1 now depends on the libv8 gem, again. So, my Gemfile has changed to:

```
group :production, :staging do
  gem 'therubyracer'
end
```

This installs the latest version of therubyracer (v0.11.1), along with the latest version of libv8 (v3.11.8.13). This has completely sorted out the issue for me - so, therubyracer v0.11.1 & libv8 v3.11.8.13 gems are installing just fine.

If that's not the case for you, then there are still options. For the Rails apps that *still* won't deploy with that, I've had success with:

```
group :production do
  gem 'libv8', '3.11.8.10'
  gem 'therubyracer'
end
```

It's also possible (and probably the better choice) to just stick with the known-good versions until all of this is sorted out by changing your Gemfile to:

```
group :production do
  gem 'therubyracer', '0.10.2'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just saying this as an alternative answer, a "downgrade of expectations", if you will

I spent 4 hours yesterday trying to get around this libv8-on-windows thing working and it turned out more than half of my gems were trying to require it. I ended up downgrading my expectations and simply running my required on-windows operations directly from ruby, loading ActiveRecord and ActiveSupport gems, etc, as necessary.

I know this isn't a good answer, and its probably not what you want to hear. But windows and rails don't seem to be playing nicely.

Comment: This particular issue was isolated to a certain version range, and occurred for me on Debian Linux (it worked fine on my local Mac OS environment). My particular question/answer didn't involve Windows at all, but I don't really disagree with you (based on what I've heard) that Windows & Rails just don't work that well together.